Why are spinors members of minimal ideals?
Why do we require that spinors live in minimal left ideals of Clifford algebras and not just left ideals? I assume that it has something to do with irreps but a Dirac spinor also lives in an minimal left ideal.

It seems like an over complication. Sure you can use non-minimal left ideals, but it is like doing classical mechanics with $n>3$-dimensional reducible representation for SO(3) rotations, it is just tiresome and unnecessary.

@Mauricio but than it would be possible to define a spinor as just an element in the Clifford algebra since this is trivial a left ideal.
